# How to display please wait message while data is being read from a log in python to render in a html page

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm reading a huge excel file for necessary data and rendering it in a html page.I use Python flask. Python file reads the .csv and renders the filtered data to a html page. 
As the excel file is huge, python takes more time to filter data and render it. In user point of view, he sees a blank loading page in his browser till the data fetch is completed and page gets rendered. 
I need to show the user a please wait message while data is being read by the python.

I tried jQuery preloaders. But python renders the template where the preloader is set after the data fetch is completed. So,basically the long loading page is present. After python renders the template, preloader appears for a second and actual page is displayed.

I also tried using Markup in Flask,even that didnt provide the result i was expecting.

I except the python file to display "please wait" message in webpage while reading data from excel and rendering it in a html template.

Any approach suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your relevant JavaScript and Python code?

Comment: Excerpt from filetohtml.py                                                                                                   ` platformdict[every_platform]=deepcopy(featuredict)

                    moduledict[mod]=deepcopy(platformdict)      
              
              return render_template('per.html',response=moduledict)`                                       This reads data from csv converts to json and renders per.html. In per.html the json data is parsed and displayed in a table. My problem is I couldnt display "please wait" message in new tab where the per.html is being rendered